# C# LINQ Add to list every regex value group

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have this code

```
Regex containsDelimitersInBrackets = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");

foreach (Match match in containsDelimitersInBrackets.Matches(_sequence))
    _separator.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

I'd like to use LINQ to add each value of each group to the `_separator` list.

I've tried this.

```
 _separator.AddRange(containsDelimitersInBrackets.Matches(_sequence).Where(x => x.Groups[1].Value));
```

but it doesn't work. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: what is your regex trying to find?

Comment: Groups of strings inside `[ ]` brackets. For example `[Hello] this is a [test]` the list should contain Hello and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matches can return 1 or more Matches, so you can get the group 1 value(s) from the Match(es) using Select and then flatten that collection using SelectMany to get each value of each group separately.

Then you can use addRange to add the collection to the `_separator` list.

For example

```
List<string> _separator = new List<string>(){"existing item"};
Regex containsDelimitersInBrackets = new Regex(@"\[([^][]*)]");

List<string> _sequence = new List<string>(){"test[1] test[2]", "test[123]"}
.SelectMany(s => 
    containsDelimitersInBrackets.Matches(s)
    .Select(m => 
        m.Groups[1].Value
    )
).ToList();

_separator.AddRange(_sequence);
_separator.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Output

```
item one
1
2
123
```

Note that instead of the non greedy quantifier, you can also use a negated character class to prevent some backtracking.

```
Regex containsDelimitersInBrackets = new Regex(@"\[([^][]*)]");
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/4TE8WO).

Answer (score 1):

You were close..

We don't use *.Where* to project value x (i.e. a `Match` object) into value y (i.e. a string), we use *.Select*

```
_separator.AddRange(containsDelimitersInBrackets
  .Matches(_sequence)
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
);
```

You also need a `.Cast<T>()` when working with old school xxxCollection classes to make LINQ work easily with the type returned from their enumerators.. Otherwise the compiler treats it as an enuemration of objects and you don't ver a very helpful intellisense. ( If you wrote `foreach(var m in someMatchCollection)` then `m` would be `object`.. When you write `foreach(Match m in someMatchCollection)` it takes the type hint from how you declared `m`)